# Как корректно вписать js код?

Tags: javascript

Редактирую форму валидации на js и мне нужно в случае выполнения условия чтобы добавлялось уведомление, я добавил строчку:

`document.getElementById('demo3').innerHTML = "<p class="myerror">Form Submitted</p>";`

Итог, но скрипт вызывает ошибку синтаксиса, как исправить?

```
if(nameVal.length < 2) {
                name.css({'box-shadow':'inset 0 0 10px red'});
                document.getElementById('demo3').innerHTML = "<p class="myerror">Form Submitted</p>";
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас проблема с ковычками, двочйные внутри двойных и приводит к ошибке синтаксиса, нужно экранировать как минимум:

```
document.getElementById('demo3').innerHTML = "<p class=\"myerror\">Form Submitted</p>";
```

Или в одинарных сделать:

```
document.getElementById('demo3').innerHTML = '<p class="myerror">Form Submitted</p>';
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Подскажите, а как сделать в условиях else и чтобы добавленный текст скрывался

Comment: Удалять можно блок по этому селектору, раз вы его в `if` добавляете, или изначально добавлять скрытым, а по if/else скрывать и показывать блок, это уже другой вопрос, его нужно задавать отдельно, чтобы получить для него ответ.